# Using Tensorflow's object detection API and program it to detect collision between detected objects

Tags: python, tensorflow

If I am using Tensorflow's object detection API can I program it to detect collision between detected objects? Such as collision of two people walking into each other and Collision of hands[high five].

Comment: The object detection output should be a class with bounding box co-ordinates. In theory, all you need to do is compare the bounding box co-ordinates and see if they overlap. If only we lived in a 2D world....! You will actually have to see if the bounding boxes interact because occlusion will cause overlap but doesn't mean collision.

Comment: what if I train high five as a new object so when two hands touch each other,the program detects a new object.Do you think it will work?

Comment: Actually, it might be possible to use the size of the bounding box as a measure of scale - if the people or hands are the same scale, then they are on the same plane. You will be able to get something that works roughly so it is worth a try, just be aware that too much bounding box overlap probably means occlusion rather than collision.